# dynamic block to skip vpc config to lambda

Tags: terraform

I would like to skip adding a vpc to lambda in certain env. The current terraform code to update vpc is like below

```
data "aws_subnet" "lambda-private-subnet_1" {
  availability_zone = var.environment_type_tag != "prd" ? "us-east-1a" : null
  dynamic "filter" {
    for_each = var.environment_type_tag == "prd" ? [] : [1]
    content {
      name   = "tag:Name"
      values = [var.subnet_value]
    }
  }
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "tests" {
  dynamic "vpc_config" {
    for_each = var.environment_type_tag == "prd" ? [] : [1]
    content {
      subnet_ids         = [data.aws_subnet.lambda-private-subnet_1.id]
      security_group_ids = [var.security_group]
    }
  }
}
```

During 'terraform plan', the output is like below

```
##[error][1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mmultiple EC2 Subnets matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single EC2 Subnet[0m
```

I would like to skip the 'data "aws_subnet"' block if its 'prd' environment type.

Comment: Your code already achieves the desired objective. The error message is due to the fact that your filters match multiple subnets in `prd`, and therefore you need to constrain the filter conditions.

Comment: okay. but I thought, the 'for_each' loop will skip entire content block in 'prd' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are four different questions in this question. We can attempt to answer each one:

1. dynamic block to skip vpc config to lambda

This is already occurring with the given code. The dynamic blocks are "skipped" in `prd` with the current code.

2. I would like to skip adding a vpc to lambda in certain env.

If you mean "subnet" instead of "vpc", then this is also already occurring with the given code. Otherwise, please update with the `vpc` config.

3. > ##[error][1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mmultiple EC2 Subnets matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single EC2 Subnet[0m

The error message is due to the fact that your filters match multiple subnets outside of `prd`, and therefore you need to constrain the filter conditions.

4. I would like to skip the 'data "aws_subnet"' block if its 'prd' environment type.

You just need to extend your current code to make the `data` optional:

```
data "aws_subnet" "lambda-private-subnet_1" {
  for_each = var.environment_type_tag == "prd" ? [] : toset(["this"])
  ...
}
```

You can then remove the `for_each` from the dynamic block in the resource as it is redundant, and update the attribute references with elements accordingly:

```
subnet_ids = [data.aws_subnet.lambda-private-subnet_1["this"].id]
```

Comment: The Point 4 worked. thanks.